# Ag-Grid: lock a column's position to the last column

Tags: ag-grid

I am wondering if there is a way to effectively lock a column in Ag-Grid so that the column is always the very last column no matter what.

**Background**

What I am ultimately looking for is to avoid the blank space after the last column if the grid size is wider than all column width combined. This is to give the grid a consistent, professional look especially considering even/odd rows are rendered usually in different color. I would prefer the blank space also has that alternating background color.

Given there seems to be no grid property that forces the grid to render the blank space at the end as a pseudo column, I am therefore considering to add a pseudo column manually in such a way that:

- the pseudo column has no header
- the pseudo column has no data
- the pseudo column is not sortable (*achieved via `sortable: false`*)
- the pseudo column is not manually resizable (*achieved via `resizable: false`*)
- the pseudo column is the ***only*** column which has `suppressSizeToFit: false`
- **lock the pseudo column to always be the last column so that user cannot drag a column to the right side of it**

I've found a way to achieve everything apart from the last item in the above list. I know I can `suppressMovable: true` but that only ensures the column itself is not draggable, it does not prevent user from dragging a column to the right side of it.

Effectively, I am looking for something similar to `lockPosition` but instead of locking the column to the front I want to lock the column to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an eye on currently open AG-3326 issue in ag-grid backlog https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/

"Allow locking ( lockPosition ) a column to always be either the first or last columns (currently only the first column is supported)"

Answer (score 0):

> What I am ultimately looking for is to avoid the blank space after the last column if the grid size is wider than all column width combined

You could use `sizeColumnsToFit()` API for columns to adjust in size to fit the grid horizontally. Using this API, there won't be any blank space after the last column, but make sure you have not specified the width for at least one column. This is the column that will expand/shrink to fit the size of the grid.

Call `sizeColumnsToFit()` after the `gridReady` event has fired.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the column sizes that way. Column sizes are something in user's hands and persisted as his profile config on the server so that no matter where and when he launches the app the look is the same. sizeColumnsToFit adjusts the width of visible columns, hence depending on where your horizontal scroll location and how large your screen is, grid column sizes changes. What I could do is to make one pseudo column as the last column, and the only one that can  sizeColumnsToFit. The fit bit works, the "as the last column" is the bit I am struggling with

Answer (score 0):

Here is an effective workaround to lock the right-most column until AG-3326 is implemented.

```js
onColumnMoved: params => {
  const columnCount = params.columnApi.getAllColumns().filter(c => c.isVisible()).length;
  const maxIndex = columnCount - 2;
  if(params.toIndex > maxIndex) {
    params.columnApi.moveColumnByIndex(params.toIndex, maxIndex); 
  }
}
```

Any column that is moved to the right of the 'locked' column is immediately moved to the left of the 'locked' column.